# Best way to prevent crash "Context is NULL" which happens randomly when you close the app

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-context

I noticed that my apps generate errors like `Tried to access SharedPreferences but context is null object reference`. They happen very randomly when a user closes the app at the same microsecond the logic tries to access something that needs `Context` object. So the app closes, but the request is being passed and the method tries to use context object. What happens is that the app closes, but a user sees a crash popup.

This is something that does not look nice in the eyes of users.

Now, what is the mistake here? Should I really check `if (context != null)` for EACH method that deals with `Context` objects? Use `try/catch` in EVERY method that deals with the `Context`?

Or maybe I should drop habit of passing `Context` of `Activity` and use the global app's context?

So I am asking a direction how to successfully solve all such issues, not a way how to do it in the code (the later is really simple).

Comment: initialise application context in Application class and use it every where. I think it's better

Comment: does it happen often? I never had a problem like this, it must be a huge fluke if user finishs the app exactly at this time when context is needed. Is there maybe something else, that could be wrong?

Comment: "They happen very randomly when a user closes the app at the same microsecond the logic tries to access something that needs Context object" -- without stack traces, you're not going to get reliable answers here.

Answer (score 0):

When using objects that can be tied to the whole application, it's better to use `getApplicationContext()`. `SharedPreferences` for instance. You will need the activity context, only when you want to display something on the screen (adding a new fragment, showing a `DialogFragment`, things that require `FragmentManager` instance.

Make sure to respect the lifecycles of the activity/fragment, and you will not have null context. Also, you will need to check if the context is null, if you have async request, that might return after the activity was killed.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to check for 2 things:

1. whether the context is null or not
2. if you are changing some UI element whether you are allowed to do it.
   This basically means that your activity is in resumed state.

Answer (score 0):

> When your activity receives a call to the onStop() method, it's no
>   longer visible and should release almost all resources [...]. Once your activity is stopped,
>   the system might destroy the instance if it needs to recover system
>   memory. In extreme cases, the system might simply kill your app
>   process [...].

From http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/stopping.html

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    // release resources (e.g. stop/pause async tasks etc)
}
```